# re-shaping pandas dataframe (startdate, enddate) to daily and hourly columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-analysis

- i am having a dataset as below containing status info (online, offline, ...) of devices:
- the following dateframe name is historicaldata (just a sample)

```
   History_id Device_id  Status          Start_date            End_date
0      40162     AUH888       1 2018-10-22 08:33:22 2018-10-22 08:34:26
1      40163     AUH888       0 2018-10-22 08:34:26 2018-10-22 10:15:00
2      40167     AUH888       3 2018-10-22 10:15:00 2018-10-23 12:40:01
3      40224     AUH888       0 2018-10-23 12:40:01 2018-10-23 13:00:00
4      40227     AUH888       3 2018-10-23 13:00:00 2018-10-25 07:43:30
5      40296     AUH888       0 2018-10-25 07:43:30 2018-10-25 08:00:00
6      40298     AUH888       3 2018-10-25 08:00:00 2018-10-25 08:28:38
7      40301     AUH888       0 2018-10-25 08:28:38 2018-11-05 12:15:00
8      40965     AUH888       3 2018-11-05 12:15:00 2018-11-07 08:06:58
9      41085     AUH888       0 2018-11-07 08:06:58 2018-11-12 07:15:00
10     41256     AUH888       3 2018-11-12 07:15:00 2018-11-12 07:19:29
11     41257     AUH888       0 2018-11-12 07:19:29 2018-11-15 10:45:00
12     41412     AUH888       3 2018-11-15 10:45:00 2018-11-17 09:38:42
13     41469     AUH888       0 2018-11-17 09:38:42 2018-11-19 10:15:00
14     41555     AUH888       3 2018-11-19 10:15:00 2018-11-20 05:21:19
15     41581     AUH888       0 2018-11-20 05:21:19 2018-11-20 05:45:00
16     41582     AUH888       3 2018-11-20 05:45:00 2018-11-20 10:32:37
17     41594     AUH888       0 2018-11-20 10:32:37 2018-11-27 00:45:00
18     41856     AUH888       3 2018-11-27 00:45:00 2018-11-27 02:57:24
19     41858     AUH888       0 2018-11-27 02:57:24 2018-11-27 08:15:00
20     41877     AUH888       3 2018-11-27 08:15:00 2018-11-27 08:16:16
21     41878     AUH888       0 2018-11-27 08:16:16 2018-11-27 15:00:00
22     41900     AUH888       3 2018-11-27 15:00:00 2018-11-27 17:55:37
23     41902     AUH888       0 2018-11-27 17:55:37 2018-12-07 12:15:00
24     42301     AUH888       3 2018-12-07 12:15:00 2018-12-07 12:21:48
25     42302     AUH888       0 2018-12-07 12:21:48 2018-12-12 07:30:00
26     42518     AUH888       3 2018-12-12 07:30:00 2018-12-12 11:42:39
27     42542     AUH888       0 2018-12-12 11:42:39 2018-12-27 10:00:00
28     43319     AUH888       3 2018-12-27 10:00:00 2018-12-27 10:06:39
29     43320     AUH888       0 2018-12-27 10:06:39 2018-12-30 07:30:00
30     43437     AUH888       3 2018-12-30 07:30:00 2018-12-30 07:42:18
31     43438     AUH888       0 2018-12-30 07:42:18 2018-12-30 10:00:00
32     43445     AUH888       3 2018-12-30 10:00:00 2018-12-30 14:09:08
33     43447     AUH888       0 2018-12-30 14:09:08 2019-01-03 12:15:00
34     43566     AUH888       3 2019-01-03 12:15:00 2019-01-03 14:57:34
35     43572     AUH888       0 2019-01-03 14:57:34 2019-01-06 06:45:00
36     43656     AUH888       3 2019-01-06 06:45:00 2019-01-06 12:09:59
37     43677     AUH888       0 2019-01-06 12:09:59 2019-01-09 08:45:00
38     43835     AUH888       3 2019-01-09 08:45:00 2019-01-09 09:11:15
39     43837     AUH888       0 2019-01-09 09:11:15 2019-02-09 15:00:00
40     44866     AUH888       3 2019-02-09 15:00:00 2019-02-09 15:25:45
41     44867     AUH888       0 2019-02-09 15:25:45 2019-02-11 08:00:00
42     44956     AUH888       3 2019-02-11 08:00:00 2019-02-12 16:20:42
43     45139     AUH888       0 2019-02-12 16:20:42 2019-02-12 16:45:06
44     45142     AUH888       3 2019-02-12 16:45:06 2019-02-12 17:08:52
45     45146     AUH888       0 2019-02-12 17:08:52 2019-02-12 17:30:00
46     45154     AUH888       3 2019-02-12 17:30:00 2019-02-12 18:32:14
47     45177     AUH888       0 2019-02-12 18:32:14 2019-02-12 18:45:00
48     45179     AUH888       3 2019-02-12 18:45:00 2019-02-12 19:36:39
49     45186     AUH888       0 2019-02-12 19:36:39 2019-02-12 20:00:00
50     40905     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 14:00:00 2018-11-04 14:38:06
51     40906     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 14:38:06 2018-11-04 15:00:00
52     40908     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 15:00:00 2018-11-04 15:14:46
53     40909     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 15:14:46 2018-11-04 16:15:00
54     40911     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 16:15:00 2018-11-04 17:14:25
55     40913     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 17:14:25 2018-11-04 17:45:00
56     40914     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 17:45:00 2018-11-04 18:08:18
57     40915     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 18:08:18 2018-11-04 18:30:00
58     40916     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 18:30:00 2018-11-04 19:30:23
59     40920     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 19:30:23 2018-11-04 19:45:00
60     40921     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 19:45:00 2018-11-04 19:48:24
61     40922     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 19:48:24 2018-11-04 20:00:00
62     40923     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 20:00:00 2018-11-04 20:10:30
63     40924     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 20:10:30 2018-11-04 21:00:00
64     40926     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 21:00:00 2018-11-04 21:48:59
65     40928     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 21:48:59 2018-11-04 22:00:00
66     40929     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 22:00:00 2018-11-04 22:19:47
67     40930     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 22:19:47 2018-11-04 22:30:00
68     40931     SHJ656       3 2018-11-04 22:30:00 2018-11-04 22:49:15
69     40932     SHJ656       0 2018-11-04 22:49:15 2018-11-05 04:15:00
70     40935     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 04:15:00 2018-11-05 04:16:08
71     40936     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 04:16:08 2018-11-05 04:30:00
72     40937     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 04:30:00 2018-11-05 04:32:56
73     40938     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 04:32:56 2018-11-05 05:30:00
74     40940     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 05:30:00 2018-11-05 05:37:06
75     40941     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 05:37:06 2018-11-05 06:15:00
76     40942     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 06:15:00 2018-11-05 07:37:07
77     40943     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 07:37:07 2018-11-05 08:00:00
78     40944     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 08:00:00 2018-11-05 08:56:24
79     40945     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 08:56:24 2018-11-05 09:15:00
80     40948     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 09:15:00 2018-11-05 10:50:37
81     40950     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 10:50:37 2018-11-05 11:15:00
82     40955     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 11:15:00 2018-11-05 17:13:33
83     40973     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 17:13:33 2018-11-05 17:45:00
84     40974     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 17:45:00 2018-11-05 18:01:47
85     40975     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 18:01:47 2018-11-05 18:15:00
86     40976     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 18:15:00 2018-11-05 18:17:46
87     40977     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 18:17:46 2018-11-05 18:30:00
88     40978     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 18:30:00 2018-11-05 18:51:29
89     40979     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 18:51:29 2018-11-05 19:30:00
90     40980     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 19:30:00 2018-11-05 19:31:58
91     40981     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 19:31:58 2018-11-05 20:00:00
92     40982     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 20:00:00 2018-11-05 20:00:19
93     40983     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 20:00:19 2018-11-05 20:15:00
94     40984     SHJ656       3 2018-11-05 20:15:00 2018-11-05 20:24:21
95     40985     SHJ656       0 2018-11-05 20:24:21 2018-11-06 02:30:00
96     40990     SHJ656       3 2018-11-06 02:30:00 2018-11-06 02:38:25
97     40991     SHJ656       0 2018-11-06 02:38:25 2018-11-06 03:15:00
98     40992     SHJ656       3 2018-11-06 03:15:00 2018-11-06 03:15:12
99     40993     SHJ656       0 2018-11-06 03:15:12 2018-11-06 03:45:00
```

- the status column contain four status (online, offline, failed, lost_communication).
- Each device is streaming status data with the start and end date of each status
- each status could be a period of seconds, minutes, days or even months, so it will be difficult to visualize the data daily or hourly.
- i need to analyse the status to show the availability per status in daily basis and hourly basis to detect the fluctuation in status if exist.
- my goal is to reshape the dateframe to a new daily dataframe as followed:

```
device_id   year    month   day dow   uptimeSec downtimeSec
AUH888          2018    10  22  Monday    36836         49564
SHJ656          2018    10  24  Wednesday 44979         41421
AUH888          2018    10  25  Thursday  56872         29528
SHJ656          2018    10  29  Monday    38070         48330
```

- uptime >> when status online
- downtime >> when status is (offline, failed, lost_communication)
- i am using the following code but it is very a little bit slow.

```py
cleandataHeader = ['device_id', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'dow', 'uptimeSec', 'downtimeSec']

def fragmentCollect(daystart, dayend, device):
    maskBigFrag = ((historicaldata['Device_id'] == device) & ((daystart < historicaldata['Start_date']) & (dayend > historicaldata['End_date'])))
    BigFragdf = historicaldata.loc[maskBigFrag]
    BigFragdf['fragment'] = (BigFragdf['End_date'] - BigFragdf['Start_date']).dt.total_seconds()

    maskSmallFrag = ((historicaldata['Device_id'] == device) & ((daystart > historicaldata['Start_date']) & (dayend < historicaldata['End_date'])))
    SmallFragdf = historicaldata.loc[maskSmallFrag]
    SmallFragdf['fragment'] = (dayend - daystart).total_seconds()
    SmallFragdf['Start_date'] = daystart.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
    SmallFragdf['End_date'] = dayend.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

    maskHeadFrag = ((historicaldata['Device_id'] == device) & ((daystart >= historicaldata['Start_date'] ) & (daystart < historicaldata['End_date'] ) & (dayend > historicaldata['End_date'] )))
    HeadFragdf = historicaldata.loc[maskHeadFrag]
    HeadFragdf['fragment'] = (HeadFragdf['End_date'] - daystart).dt.total_seconds()
    HeadFragdf['Start_date'] = daystart.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

    maskTailFrag = ((historicaldata['Device_id'] == device) & ((daystart < historicaldata['Start_date'] ) & (dayend <= historicaldata['End_date'] ) & (dayend > historicaldata['Start_date'] )))
    TailFragdf = historicaldata.loc[maskTailFrag]
    TailFragdf['fragment'] = (dayend - TailFragdf['Start_date']).dt.total_seconds()
    TailFragdf['End_date'] = dayend.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')

    frames = [BigFragdf, SmallFragdf, HeadFragdf, TailFragdf]
    result = pd.concat(frames)
    result = result.drop_duplicates()
    return result

def rowClean(row):
    row['Player Name'] = row.name[1]
    row['year'] = row.name[0].year
    row['month'] = row.name[0].month
    row['day'] = row.name[0].day
    row['dow'] = row.name[0].day_name()
    result = fragmentCollect(row.name[0], row.name[0] + timedelta(days=1), row.name[1])
    result = result.to_dict('records')
    uptime = 0
    downtime = 0
    for frag in result:
        if frag['status'] == 'Online':
            uptime += frag['fragment']
        else:
            downtime += frag['fragment']
    row['uptimeSec'] = uptime 
    row['downtimeSec'] = downtime
    return row

def buildTheCleanData(start, end):
    datelist = [start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end-start).days + 1)]
    iterables = [datelist,['AUH888', 'SHJ656']
    Index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['date', 'Device_id'])
    s = pd.DataFrame(columns = cleandataHeader, index = Index)
    s = s.apply(rowClean, axis=1)
    return s
```

- function fragmentCollect is my algorithm to collect the fragment of status for each start, end, device passed.
- function rowClean will be applyed on each row in the new multiindex dataframe to fill the info (uptimesec, downtimesec).
- buildTheCleanData function used to build the a new clean dataframe of availability status by day.
- i can apply the same concept if i want a clean dataframe by day by hour.
- as you can see my code above is very slow.
- i was wondering if there is a build in pandas function that deals with a similar situations which much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

What could be done here would be to first split rows spanning on different days to ensure that each row belongs to one single day. The rows to split are those where the date (day) is different for Start_date and End_date. Then, the initial row would be ended at the end of first day, and additional rows would be prepared for every new day in the range [Start_date, End_date).

Once this is done, it becomes easy to add for each row a date, and the uptime and downtime durations. After summing those durations for each pair Device_id, date we get your expected result.

Code could be:

```
# list of days to split
new_days = df[df.Start_date.dt.date != df.End_date.dt.date].copy()

# initialize Start_date to the end of the initial days for the new days to add
new_days['Start_date'] = (new_days.Start_date + pd.offsets.Day()).dt.floor('D')

# in original dataframe, End_date is at end of day of Start_date
df.loc[new_days.index, 'End_date'] = new_days['Start_date']

# number of full days to add
days_to_add = (new_days.End_date - new_days.Start_date).dt.floor('D').dt.days

# build a list of those days
splitted = []
for i, row in new_days.iterrows():
    r = row.copy()
    for i in range(days_to_add.loc[i]):
        r['End_date'] = r['Start_date'] + pd.offsets.Day()
        splitted.append(r.copy())
        r['Start_date'] = r['End_date']

# last to add will have Start_date at the beginning of day of End_date
new_days['Start_date'] = new_days['End_date'].dt.floor('D')

# add those new days to the original dataframe (in an intermediate dataframe)    
interm = pd.concat([df, new_days[new_days.Start_date!=new_days.End_date],
                   pd.DataFrame(splitted)]).rename_axis('ix').reset_index()
# interm = interm.sort_values(['ix', 'Start_date']).set_index('ix')
# interm.rename_axis('', inplace=True)

# add required columns to the intermediate dataframe
interm["year"] = interm.Start_date.dt.year
interm["month"] = interm.Start_date.dt.month
interm["day"] = interm.Start_date.dt.day
interm["dow"] = interm.Start_date.dt.strftime('%A')
interm['uptimeSec'] = np.where(interm.Status == 0,
                              (interm.End_date - interm.Start_date).dt.seconds
                              + 86400 * (interm.End_date - interm.Start_date
                                         ).dt.days,
                              0)
interm['downtimeSec'] = np.where(interm.Status != 0,
                              (interm.End_date - interm.Start_date).dt.seconds
                              + 86400 * (interm.End_date - interm.Start_date
                                         ).dt.days,
                              0)

# sum the durations
reshaped = interm[['Device_id', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'dow', 'uptimeSec',
                   'downtimeSec']].groupby(['Device_id', 'year', 'month',
                                            'day', 'dow']).sum().reset_index()
```

It gives as expected:

```
Device_id  year  month  day        dow  uptimeSec  downtimeSec
  AUH888  2018     10   22     Monday       6034        49564
  AUH888  2018     10   23    Tuesday       1199        85201
  AUH888  2018     10   24  Wednesday          0        86400
  AUH888  2018     10   25   Thursday      56872        29528
  AUH888  2018     10   26     Friday      86400            0
  AUH888  2018     10   27   Saturday      86400            0
  AUH888  2018     10   28     Sunday      86400            0
  AUH888  2018     10   29     Monday      86400            0
```

Comment: Hi Serge, Splitting really is a nice way to do this and it is really fast also ,
but as i am new to pandas i got lost `days_to_add = (new_days.End_date - new_days.Start_date).dt.floor('D').dt.days`
at the end i tried your code on my original data but i got some missing data
my original code contains data fro more than 100 devices but i don't think this  will make any difference in the code.

Comment: i tried the following `reshaped.loc[(reshaped['year'] == 2019) & (reshaped['month'] == 6) & (reshaped['day'] == 1)]` to get all the devices for 2019/06/01 
and i got only 7 devices fro that day, can you please help may be i am using loc in wronge way.

Comment: i believe your code didn't consider the records which the duration between start data and end date is more than 2 days (there is some recorde will have start date for example 24/05/2019  12:47:08 AM and end date is 09/06/2019 16:58
)

Answer (score 0):

I happened to stumble over the same problem where I had to calculate something similar but on a 15min time-frame instead of a 1 day frame. I tried to apply my solution to your problem.

1) As described by Serge Ballesta it is important to split the rows into fixed time units, in your case days. My approach was to convert the start and end-times into start-time and duration.

I tried this code with a snippet of your data that is added at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols) # data and cols as defined at end of my post

# Convert relevant entries to datetime format
df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
df['End_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date'])

# Set start_date as index
df.set_index('Start_date', inplace=True)

# Add row with duration, based on start and end-time
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['End_date'] - df.index)
```

I create a new dataFrame with daily entries (you can set the time appropriately)

```
# Online is where status is 0, offline is where status is {1,2,3}
# Step-by-step-explanation:
# df[df['Status'] == '0'] -> filters only for entries wit hstatus 'online'
# df[df['Status'] == '0']['duration'] -> of the filtered entries, select the duration row
# df[df['Status'] == '0']['duration'].resample('1d') -> resample to daily bins
# df[df['Status'] == '0']['duration'].resample('1d').sum() -> sum 'duration' per bin
#(df[df['Status'] == '0']['duration'].resample('1d').sum().astype(np.int64)/1e9) -> convert summed duration to seconds (convertion from nanoseconds!)
online = (df[df['Status'] == '0']['duration'].resample('1d').sum().astype(np.int64)/1e9)
offline = (df[(df['Status'] == '1') | (df['Status'] == '2') | (df['Status'] == '3')]['duration'].resample('1d').sum().astype(np.int64)/1e9)
index = online.index

# The new dataframe is put together
new_sort = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
new_sort['online'] = online
new_sort['offline']= offline
new_sort.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Since the time duration might be overlapping over more than one day, you might have duration entries with more than one days worth of time. I fixed this with a function. This function limits the time and if there is 'excess' time, it shifts it to the next day.

```
def split_duration(df, col, dt):
    diff = 0
    for e,row in df.iterrows():
        if diff > 0:
            row[col] += diff
            diff = 0

        if row[col]>dt:
            diff = row[col] - dt
            row[col] = dt
    return df

dt = 60*60*24 # time unit is in seconds, dt is seconds per day
df = split_duration(new_sort, 'online', dt)
df = split_duration(new_sort, 'offline', dt)
```

The resulting dataframe new_sort gives you all the information you need.

```
new_sort
            online  offline
Start_date      
2018-10-22  6034.0  86400.0
2018-10-23  1199.0  86400.0
2018-10-24  0.0     76175.0
2018-10-25  86400.0  1718.0
2018-10-26  86400.0     0.0
2018-10-27  86400.0     0.0
2018-10-28  86400.0     0.0
2018-10-29  86400.0     0.0
2018-10-30  86400.0     0.0
```

This code might still not be optimal, improvements are welcomed.
Here just the Dataframe I used with this code.

```
data = np.array([[40162,     'AUH888',       1, '2018-10-22 08:33:22', '2018-10-22 08:34:26'], 
 [40163,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-10-22 08:34:26', '2018-10-22 10:15:00'], 
 [40167,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-10-22 10:15:00', '2018-10-23 12:40:01'], 
 [40224,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-10-23 12:40:01', ' 2018-10-23 13:00:00'], 
 [40227,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-10-23 13:00:00', ' 2018-10-25 07:43:30'], 
 [40296,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-10-25 07:43:30', ' 2018-10-25 08:00:00'], 
 [40298,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-10-25 08:00:00', ' 2018-10-25 08:28:38'], 
 [40301,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-10-25 08:28:38', ' 2018-11-05 12:15:00'], 
 [40965,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-11-05 12:15:00', ' 2018-11-07 08:06:58'], 
 [41085,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-11-07 08:06:58', ' 2018-11-12 07:15:00'], 
 [41256,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-11-12 07:15:00', ' 2018-11-12 07:19:29'], 
 [41257,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-11-12 07:19:29', ' 2018-11-15 10:45:00'], 
 [41412,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-11-15 10:45:00', ' 2018-11-17 09:38:42'], 
 [41469,     'AUH888',       0, '2018-11-17 09:38:42', ' 2018-11-19 10:15:00']])
cols = ['History_id', 'Device_id','Status', 'Start_date', 'End_date']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Comment: the record with index 2018-10-24 should show offline with 86400 because in of the following record in the original df:
`40227,     'AUH888',       3, '2018-10-23 13:00:00', ' 2018-10-25 07:43:30'`

Comment: Yes, you're right. This does not work in this application. In my application, this was not a problem, for other reasons. I'll have to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

My verstion:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


def days_distance(start, end):
    A = start.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    B = end.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return (B - A).days


def duration(sdate, start=True):
    d_start = sdate.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    dur = (sdate - d_start).seconds
    return 86400 - dur if start else dur


def data_arr(tm, vl):
    return tm.year, tm.month, tm.day, tm.strftime("%A"), vl, 86400 - vl


def durs(sdate, edate):
    res = []
    if sdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == edate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
        res.append(data_arr(sdate, (edate - sdate).seconds))
    else:
        res.append(data_arr(sdate, duration(sdate)))
        res.append(data_arr(edate, duration(edate, start=False)))
    ddist = days_distance(sdate, edate)
    for i in range(1, ddist):
        res.append(data_arr(sdate + timedelta(days=i), 86400))
    return res


def expand(data_series):
    durations = durs(data_series.Start_date, data_series.End_date)
    tdf = pd.DataFrame(
        durations,
        columns=['year', 'month', 'day', 'dow', 'uptimeSec', 'downtimeSec'])
    tdf.insert(
        loc=0, column='Device_id', value=[data_series.Device_id]*len(tdf))
    return tdf


# Load source csv
df = pd.read_csv('data_files/device_statuses.csv')
df.Start_date = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_date)
df.End_date = pd.to_datetime(df.End_date)

# Keep uptime data only:
df = df[df.Status == 0]
print(df.head(), '\n\n----------\n')

# Get desired result
dfs = df.apply(lambda row: expand(row), axis=1)
result = pd.concat(dfs.to_list(), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
result.sort_values(by=['year', 'month', 'day', 'dow'])
print(result.head())
```

Output:

```
   History_id Device_id  Status          Start_date            End_date
1       40163    AUH888       0 2018-10-22 08:34:26 2018-10-22 10:15:00
3       40224    AUH888       0 2018-10-23 12:40:01 2018-10-23 13:00:00
5       40296    AUH888       0 2018-10-25 07:43:30 2018-10-25 08:00:00
7       40301    AUH888       0 2018-10-25 08:28:38 2018-11-05 12:15:00
9       41085    AUH888       0 2018-11-07 08:06:58 2018-11-12 07:15:00 

----------

  Device_id  year  month  day       dow  uptimeSec  downtimeSec
0    AUH888  2018     10   22    Monday       6034        80366
1    AUH888  2018     10   23   Tuesday       1199        85201
2    AUH888  2018     10   25  Thursday        990        85410
3    AUH888  2018     10   25  Thursday      55882        30518
4    AUH888  2018     11    5    Monday      44100        42300
```

csv:

```
History_id,Device_id,Status,Start_date,End_date
40162,AUH888,1,2018-10-22 08:33:22,2018-10-22 08:34:26
40163,AUH888,0,2018-10-22 08:34:26,2018-10-22 10:15:00
40167,AUH888,3,2018-10-22 10:15:00,2018-10-23 12:40:01
40224,AUH888,0,2018-10-23 12:40:01,2018-10-23 13:00:00
40227,AUH888,3,2018-10-23 13:00:00,2018-10-25 07:43:30
40296,AUH888,0,2018-10-25 07:43:30,2018-10-25 08:00:00
40298,AUH888,3,2018-10-25 08:00:00,2018-10-25 08:28:38
40301,AUH888,0,2018-10-25 08:28:38,2018-11-05 12:15:00
40965,AUH888,3,2018-11-05 12:15:00,2018-11-07 08:06:58
41085,AUH888,0,2018-11-07 08:06:58,2018-11-12 07:15:00
41256,AUH888,3,2018-11-12 07:15:00,2018-11-12 07:19:29
41257,AUH888,0,2018-11-12 07:19:29,2018-11-15 10:45:00
41412,AUH888,3,2018-11-15 10:45:00,2018-11-17 09:38:42
41469,AUH888,0,2018-11-17 09:38:42,2018-11-19 10:15:00
41555,AUH888,3,2018-11-19 10:15:00,2018-11-20 05:21:19
...
```